# angularjs http.get only works first time

Tags: angularjs, http

I have a function in my controller that calls an api to retrieve some values:

```
$scope.Refresh= function(){
    $http.get('/get/value')
        .success(function(data) {
            //some actions
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            //some actions
        });
} ;
```

I want to refresh the values occasionally, so I've done:

```
setInterval($scope.Refresh, 100000);
```

*I will do in a better way, but now I want to solve this.*

but there is a problem:

If, in the controller, I say: `$scope.Refresh` (to execute the function first time), the controller does nothing.

If I write the same function + setInterval (to test and run it)  it works first time (outside the function), but never refresh next times (code function inside), to explain, that execute the function but neither `.success` nor `.error` is called.

I have seen the headers with a 304 status (not modified) but the values are modified!!

I tried to disable cache but that did not fix the problem.

I tried to give a random value to the route like: `/get/value/(randomNuber)` but I get nothing

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just running:

```
$scope.Refresh();
```

should definitely run the function at least once. If it doesn't something is wrong with your code or with your server route. But you should be getting a console error if that's the case.

For `setInterval`, you should be using the `$interval` service that ensures your code is run within the angular loop.

Also, per the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24interval), you should explicitly cancel this interval when your controller is destroyed.

```
var httpInterval = $interval($scope.Refresh, 100000);

$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
  $interval.cancel(httpInterval);
});
```

Comment: Hi, many thanks.unfortunately, when i do that the function only start after the time have pass, (100000 in this case) and the console dont throw any error

Answer (score 0):

I've only had intermittent luck with `.success` and `.error`, and I'd like to think that part of it was caching the request. I have very consistent, successful results using `.then`, as shown:

```
$scope.Refresh= function(){
    var myGet = $http.get('/get/value');
    myGet.then(function(data){
        //do success things here
    }, function(data){
        //do error things here
    });
};
```

Other than that, follow the advice that @theJoeBiz gave regarding $interval and you should be fine.